# Windows Media Player library not appearing properly

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Windows Media Player library is listed 80% under unknown artist/unknown album despite each song containing the album and artist details.

The library location is usually unresponsive and Media Player 12 is usually hanging for 3 or 4 minutes every 5 or 6 minutes. Library was fine two weeks ago then I had updated and it has not worked right since.

My PC specifics:

- Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit
- 8 GB ram
- Processor 3.76 Ghz
- Primary drive 1Tb
- Secondary drive 500Gb

Default save for the library is on the secondary drive. I've already tried media player settings troubleshooter and the library troubleshooter to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try rebuilding WMP's library by following these instructions. First note that resetting the library will make you lose all current play counts, and possibly ratings too. Then, follow these steps:

- Reboot the PC.
- Go to Start, type `services.msc` in the Search field, and press Enter. In Services, find the `Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service`. If its status is `Started`, double-click the service and click `Stop`.
- Go to Start, type `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft` in the Search field, and press Enter. This folder will open up in Windows Explorer.
- In this folder, delete the `Media Player` folder. If you can't see the folder, then it's probably hidden. Set Explorer to show hidden files and folders, and to show protected system files.
- Start WMP, your library will have been reset and will be rebuilt. Check if the issues still occur.